# Bind a value and Print the External HTML using AngularJS without loading into the browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, printing, angularjs-bindings

I'm having 2 HTML Views one is for application purpose and another one is for Printing purpose. Just consider the two file names **Application.html** and **PrintForm.html**

Sample HTML Script of **Application.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
  
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}<br>
<br> Click here to <a href="#">Print</a>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sample HTML Script of PrintForm.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="visible">My First Name is {{  }}</h1>
<h1 class="visible">My Last Name is {{  }}</h1>

<p>The Value fetched from Application.html</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I click the Print hyperlink from Application.html, I need to print PrintForm.html with data binded from `app.controller` `$scope`

```
$scope.firstName = "John";
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
```

The expected output screen is

[image: Print From Application.html]

I don't need to load the Printing content into the browser, it directly trigger the Printer Dialog to print, after print hyperlink gets hit.

My expected action after hitting the Print Hyperlink in the Application.html should be as

[image: Print Dialog]

> Note: Don't use iFrame or any other inner View for the PrintForm.html

Comment: @KavinB - My Requirement is how to send data from one html to another html page, I can't able to make a innerframe. Don't think you are a extraordinary, give solution for my requirement.

Comment: @KevinB Here after don't visit my feature post, because you are polluting the post and you redirecting the vision to the wrong direction.

Comment: So, you want to click on an anchor tag, and have it... open a print dialog that prints the printer friendly view, yes? the ONLY way to do that is either to open a new window with the html you wish to print and calling `window.print()`, or by doing the same with an iFrame. Both of which are described in detail at the linked duplicate

Comment: @KevinB We don't support or use iFrame. Kindly refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice

I already specified my requirement. give your idea only within my requirement, don't change my primary requirement and model which we are following.

Comment: Then unfortunately there is no way to do what you are asking for. :)

Comment: well, i guess you could setup a print-friendly .css file that hides the content you don't want printed, then have the onclick of the anchor tag do "window.print()".

Comment: @KevinB In your experience you don't have solution. may be some other may have... then why you closed this post as duplicate.

Comment: window.print() is a basic method to print. this knows all.

Comment: @KevinB your activity irritating me. I don't have enough time to debate with you. So, I pleased here after don't interact in my post. I expecting some solution, but your activity puts speed-break. Don't do that.

Comment: Update your question with the additional requirements that would make using an iframe or another window not an option, and i'll reopen it.

Comment: @KevinB There is no need to add additional requirement. Enough information is already there.

Comment: The only solution available to you can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2005833/400654 otherwise I would provide an answer here directly, but that would just be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
  
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}<br>
<br> Click here to <a href="#" ng-click="printDiv('PrintID')">Print</a>

</div>

<div id="PrintID" style="visibility: collapse;">
<h1 class="visible">My First Name is {{ firstName }}</h1>
<h1 class="visible">My Last Name is {{ lastName }}</h1>

<p>The Value fetched from Application.html</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
 
 

$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Print<title></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
} 
 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Following Source Code will exactly satisfy your requirement.